# Keith Woods svg-plugin doesnt rotate my rectangle

Tags: jquery, svg, transform, rotation

Im pretty shure that this code should produce a rectangle and animate a rotation. But it doesnt rotate. What am I doing wrong?

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#intro').svg({onLoad: drawInitial});
});

function drawInitial()
{
    var svg = $('#intro').svg('get');

    var myrect = svg.rect(25, 25, 150, '25%', 10, 10, {fill: 'none', stroke: 'blue', strokeWidth: 3, transform: 'rotate(0, 100, 75)'});
    $(myrect).animate({svgTransform: 'rotate(60, 100, 75)'}, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rect elements do not hav a transform property. `<g>` and non-root `<svg>` elements do have such a property so your best bet is to make the rect's parent a `<g>` element with a transform property and then change the transform on the  element.

Comment: Thanks. That works. But now I've got another problem. I want to group a loaded svg object (made with illustrator) and an object produced with jquery. Then I want to animate them both. I dont knwo how to group them. I will post my new code above.

Comment: Why not ask a new question? I answered this as it stood.